# Loki json logs filter by detected fields from grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I am sending json logs to loki and visualizing in grafana. Initially, my logs looked like as following.

```
  {   
     "log": "{\"additionalDetails\":{\"body\":{},\"ip\":\"::ffff:1.1.1.1\",\"params\":{},\"query\":{},\"responseTime\":0,\"userAgent\":\"ELB-HealthChecker/2.0\"},\"context\":\"http\",\"endpoint\":\"/healthz\",\"level\":\"info\",\"message\":\"[::ffff:1.1.1.1] HTTP/1.1 GET 200 /healthz 0ms\",\"requestId\":\"9fde4910-86cd-11ec-a1c5-cd8277a61e4a\",\"statusCode\":200}\n",   
     "stream": "stdout",   
     "time": "2022-02-05T21:49:58.178290044Z" 
  }
```

To make it more usable, I am using following query.

```
{app="awesome-loki-logs-with-grafana"} | json | line_format "{{.log}}"
```

And the results are really good. It automaticaly detects fileds as following.

[image]

How can I filter by statusCode, which is already being detected by grafana?

Comment: Did the answer work for you? Could you accept it?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira, Yes I accept the answer. It worked for me.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira you have to hit the check next to the answer to accept it.  Saying "I accept the answer" in a comment is not sufficient.

Comment: Done! Appreciate your help. Thanks a ton. @MarceloÁviladeOliveira

Comment: No @Timam you clicked on the "up arrow"  and, this way, you have signaled that "the answer is useful". To accept the answer, you have to click on the "checkmark" next to the arrows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a "status" custom variable with values like 200, 401, 403, 404, etc, and use the variable in the LogQL, like in the following example:

```
{app="awesome-loki-logs-with-grafana"} | json | statusCode=$status
```

Comment: I think it should be = instead of ==.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create a label from the detected field so you can filter with the values you want:

```
{app="awesome-loki-logs-with-grafana"} | json statusCode="statusCode" | statusCode == $MY_FILTER_VALUE
```

For more information check [grafana official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#json).

Comment: I think it should be = instead of ==.